Loop invariant proof, nth fibonacci number
The code below calculates the nth Fibonacci number. Do you know the mathematical formula used in this algorithm? I couldn't prove the loop invariant here.
if n == 0:
    return 0

a = 1
b = 1

for i in range(1,n):
    c = b - i       
    b = c + a       
    a = c + 2*i + 1
   
return b 


This reduces to the usual recurrence for the Fibonacci sequence.
Write the recurrences for $b(i)$ and $a(i)$, inline the definition of $c$, and substitute to eliminate $a(i)$. Be careful with indices. The inclusion of $i$ in the sums is there to distract you and completely cancels out.

I took a(i) as F(i) and b(i) as F(i+1) and couldn't cancel out i's

It's not true that $a(i) = F(i)$. But you shouldn't need to relate $a$ to the Fibonacci sequence if you follow the procedure I outlined above.
